# Tracking user web search history in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, proxy, http-proxy, user-tracking

I am implementing a Django powered website in which I need to track the websites visited by a logged in user.I had googled it but didn't find anything specific to Django.

I know there is a documentation available at [link](https://www.djangoproject.com/)

Can anyone please recommend some django specific document or some algorithm which is independent of the web browsers.

Thanks .

**Edit:** The django application would be acting like a portal which will authenticate users to use internet.The search will not be on the django powered website as it would just act as a portal for login,logout.

Comment: You could create a middleware and a simple model to log each request

Comment: Thanks,I understood your point regarding the model,but can you please elaborate about middleware?

Comment: @Brobin I'm interested in knowing a bit more about this approach!

Comment: The accepted answer is pretty much what I do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on various things and you will probably get very different answers.

One way would be to store a list of urls in `request.session` as a session cookie value.

If you need more persistence, you could create your own model for it and save it on each request. Something like:

```
class Tracker(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField()
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

However this can be relatively slow depending how intense you plan to use it.

If you need to store much of this kind of data, it might be worth it to investigate adding a database backend like `influxdb` which is designed to store a lot of time series data for later statistical evaluation.

Comment: Thanks,but how will I know if a request is issued as it can be made on any tab,this django website would just be representing a portal after which a user is authenticated to use internet.Can you please elaborate how to track a request?

Comment: @ssharma not sure I understand what you mean "can be made on any tab"  or "authenticated to use internet". I understood it that way, that you want to track the user on your page. You can't track what a user does elsewhere.

Comment: the application would be just like a portal,for example in colleges, generally students need to login to a portal with their college credentials to be authenticated to use internet.

Comment: @ssharma I see. This leaves my field of expertise. I suspect this might need some server/proxy setup to work and to make that work with your backend you would have to pass it through Django or deliver the data 
there by other means. Sorry if I can't help you more. Good luck with your implementation.